# C++ code pass compling but return Segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code for practising sequence list and it passed the complier. However, when I try to run it, it returns Segmentation fault. Please help!! Thanks a lot.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SeqList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    SeqList seq;

    string vv[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

    for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++) {
        seq.addElement(vv[i], i);

    }

    string* v  = seq.getSeq();
    for (int i=0; i<seq.getSeqSize(); i++) {
        cout << v[i] <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

SeqList.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class SeqList {

    private:
        string seq[];
        int size;

    public:
        void addElement(string, int);
        void delElement(string, int);
        string* getSeq();
        int getSeqSize();

};
```

SeqList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "SeqList.h"

using namespace std;


string seq[100];
int size = 0;

string* SeqList::getSeq(){
    return seq;
};

int SeqList::getSeqSize(){
    return size;
};

void SeqList::addElement(string str, int pos) {
    int i;
    for (i = size; i > pos; i--) {
        seq[i] = seq[i-1];
    }
    seq[i-1] = str;
    size++;
};
```

Comment: You can try debugging the program. The debugger should stop at the place of the segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your segfault is happening because you're trying to access `seq[i-1]` in addElement when `i = 0`. This tries to access the memory outside of `seq` which causes a segfault. Try using `seq[i]` and `seq[i+1]` instead of `seq[i-1]` and `seq[i]`, though you'll have to make sure you never call that code with more than 99 values or you'll run into a similar problem where the program tries to access memory past the end of `seq`.

Also, in SeqList.cpp

```
string seq[100];
int size = 0;
```

These lines are creating new variables, when it looks like you're trying to change the values you made in SeqList.h. To change those private values in your class you should either use a constructor or other function to initialize the values.

Comment: hi Candlemancer. Thanks for your reply. However, I dont' think i can be 0, cause in the for-loop condition, i>pos, where pos is from 0 ~ 3.

Comment: That is true, but underneath the for loop the next statement is seq[i-1]. So the function will start, i will be declared, the for loop will set i = 0, then check to see if 0 > pos. It's not, so it skips the for loop, but then the next statement tries to assign seq[-1] = str; which will cause problems.